# Laravel API TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, api, laravel, token

I have an API call with post data; let's say this is the login process.

With the Postman extension of Chrome I send, via POST, the username and password to log the user in.
But I got this message:

```
Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException
```

In my Base Controller I have:

```
    /**
     * Initializer.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // CSRF Protection
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));

        // Layouts/Notifications
        $this->messageBag = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

    }
```

When I delete the row with the beforeFilter everything works fine.
But this cannot be a solution.
Any POST call would get this error message. 
I KNOW that I need this _token. But how I get this token when I call from the API? I know that I can create a token inside Laravel, but how can I do this when I call from outside via API?

Comment: Because you need to send the token through as a parameter, as the csrf filter will check the _token field of the input. If you are not sending it this check will fail.

Comment: ok. sry for ambiguous description... I KNOW that I need this _token. But how I get this token when I Call the API? I know that I can create a token inside laravel, but how can I do this when I call from outside via API ?

Comment: Generally API's are used for cross site requests. So your CSRF protection is pointless. Its mainly used for applications and web sites. But disable it on the logging in, and then on successful log in send the user the csrf_token value by calling the helper `csrf_token();`

Comment: thanks. How can I disable the `$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));` on some requests? I have this line in the __construct function of my base Controller? So I WANT that this is generally a before filter, but in some cases The before filter should be disabled. is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally API's are used for cross site requests. So your CSRF protection is pointless.

If you're not gonna use it cross-site, chances are that an API is not the optimal solution for what you're trying to do. Anyway, you *could* make an API endpoint which returns a token.

```
public function getToken(){
    return Response::json(['token'=>csrf_token()]);
}
```

**If you want to disable CSRF-protection on some methods**, you could use `except` or `only`.

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post', 
                                 'except'=>array('methodName', 'anotherMethod')
                                  ));
```

Please refer to the [official Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters).

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely **[don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944512/laravel-api-tokenmismatchexception/33212007#33212007)** this approach.

Open `VerifyCsrfToken` class and define `$except` property which will contain an array of routes, where CSRF protection won't be applied.

Example below:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'api/auth/login',
        'api/*', // this works as well
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just listen to this. Just before 30 minute i was facing this same problem. Now it solved. just try this.

Goto App -> HTTP-> Kernel

open the kernel file.

there you can see :
 \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

just disable this particular code using //

Thatz it! This will work!

So that you can remove the middleware from the API calling (if you want so..)