# Post method fail with Vue.js "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

So I'm trying to store data in my election_users table but making a POST request gives a "500 (Internal Server Error)" error. My object does return the right "election_id". I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

here's my method in my vue script:

```
methods: {
      createVote: function () {
        var itemId = this.$route.params.id
        var input = this.newUserVoted
        this.newUserVoted.election_id = itemId
        this.$http.post('http://www.nmdad2-05-elector.local/api/v1/electionuser', input)
          .then((response) => {
            this.newUserVoted = {'election_id': itemId}
          }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
            console.log(input)
          })
      }
    },
```

my UsersController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $userVoted = new ElectionUser();
        $userVoted->election_id = $request['election_id'];
        $userVoted->user_id = Auth::id();

        if ($userVoted->save()) {


            return response()
                ->json($userVoted);

        }

    }
```

my routesApi.php

```
   Route::post( 'electionuser', 'UsersController@store' );
```

My ElectionUser.php

```
class ElectionUser extends Model
{
    // Relationships
    // =============

    protected $fillable = [
        'election_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function election()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Election::class);
    }
```

}

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the error the page gives. It could be a CSRF error, or you forget to use Auth, or a lot of other stuff. (Press f12 and go to network)

Comment: it says "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:"

Comment: Look at one of these questions for some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944512/laravel-api-tokenmismatchexception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383165/tokenmismatchexception-for-api-in-laravel-5-2-31 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118400/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSRF token:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-csrf-token

For example in the view

```
<script>
  var csrf = '{{csrf_token()}}';
</script>
```

And in your script

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('_token', csrf);
formData.append('input', this.newUserVoted);

this.$http.post('http://www.nmdad2-05-elector.local/api/v1/electionuser', formData)
```